# Add firebase console user with permission to add Auth users, but not delete database

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-console, google-iam

I have a client who wants access to the Firebase console so they can add users manually themselves in the Authentication module.

I tried to add them via "Users and Permissions" but could not find any roles which fit adding users in authentication and no write permission in the database.

For the moment I added them as Project Editor, but not comfortable with it.

Answer (score 1):

Granting admin access to your app dashboard is probably not the right answer for administrating in-app users. It could even be a security risk. It is, in my mind, equivalent to giving your app users access to your physical server via a shell prompt instead of creating an API for them to call.

A better alternative here would be to set up a Google Cloud Functions endpoint which would accept API requests and create users on their behalf, validating their access privileges by some criteria you determine.

1) [Enable and deploy](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started) Cloud Functions

2) Set up an [Authenticated HTTPS endpoint](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/Node-8/authorized-https-endpoint)

3) Function code for creating a new user would look something like this:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();
const express = require('express');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser')();
const cors = require('cors')({origin: true});
const app = express();

// See https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/Node-8/authorized-https-endpoint/functions/index.js
const validateFirebaseIdToken = require('./validateFirebaseIdToken');

app.use(cors);
app.use(cookieParser);
app.use(validateFirebaseIdToken);
app.get('/createUser', (req, res) => {

  const userData = req.params;

  // This represents some criteria you set for determining who can call this endpoint
  // possible a list of approved uids in your database?
  if( req.user.uid !== VALID_ADMIN_USER ) {
    res.status(401).send('Unauthorized');
    return;
  }

  // See https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#create_a_user

  admin.auth().createUser({
    email: userData.email,
    displayName: userData.name,
    ...
  })
    .then(function(userRecord) {
      // See the UserRecord reference doc for the contents of userRecord.
      res.json({result: 'success', uid: userRecord.uid});
      console.log("Successfully created new user:", userRecord.uid);
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.error("Failed to create new user");
      console.error(error);
      res.status(500).json({status: 'error', error: 'Unable to process the request'});
    });

});

// This HTTPS endpoint can only be accessed by your Firebase Users.
// Requests need to be authorized by providing an `Authorization` HTTP header
// with value `Bearer <Firebase ID Token>`.
exports.app = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

4) Provide the API endpoint to your client or build a rudimentary app/web interface they can use that calls this endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

So go to the Google Cloud Platform(from Firebase Console) and then choose Manage Roles from where you can create `Custom roles`.

**Note that Custom Roles is currently in Beta and you might not be able to achieve what you need but as docs suggest**:

> Custom roles let you group permissions and assign them to members of
>   your project or organization. You can manually select permissions or
>   import permissions from another role.

Comment: There are are an insane amount of customization. Which roles correspond with authentication? When using the default roles, I found that missing some roles made it impossible to even access the console.

Comment: The product is in Beta so I believe it might still not be listed. So, currently you can't achieve that functionality